# Media keys work periodically with media player on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, media

I'm on Linux Mint 19. Sometimes my media keys (play, pause, next, etc.) work fine with media apps (Spotify, in my case). Sometimes they do not work, and sometimes they even end up controlling media in my browser. Even though there is nothing in browsers, they do not "connect" to Spotify. What can I do?

Media keys works nice on Chrome.

Comment: Please test media key function in other apps, then click [edit] and add results to original question. Please do not click Add Comment; please use [edit].

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, the browser (in my case, Google Chrome) was "holding" the media keys when it was playing something. Even without browser media, the keys were only allocated for Chrome.

One possible solution:

1. Paste chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling at Chrome;
2. Select "Disable" at first option;
3. Open spotify and enjoy!

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to close Chrome (and use htop to kill *all* processes of Chrome) and restart Spotify for this to work.